# Python - автоматическое заполнение

Tags: python

Задача такова, у меня заполняются переменные через POST запрос, обрабатываются сервером. Далее, я хочу с помощью этих переменных поменять дату и время на linux(RPi).

```
_year = request.form['_year']
    _month = request.form['_month']
    _day = request.form['_day']
    _hour = request.form['_hour']
    _minute = request.form['_minute']
    _second = request.form['_second']
    os.system('date -s "%d %s %d %d:%d:%d"') % (_day, _month, _year, _hour, _minute, _second)
```

подскажите пожалуйста почему `"%d %s %d %d:%d:%d"` не работает?

Comment: Потому что % вызывается не у строки, а у результата вызова os.system

Comment: Впрочем, и исправленный код тоже не заработает из-за подстановки строк в %d, а если исправить и это, то такой код станет дырой в безопасности, потому что злой юзер отправит месяц `Jan; rm -rf /* #`

Comment: @andreymal немного не понял на счет отправки

Comment: @Insider это к тому, что в результате выполнения запроса `request.form['_month']` клиент может подсунуть значение `Jan; rm -rf /*` (в результате выполнится рекурсивное удаление всего в корне ФС) или еще что-то опасное. То есть, совет вам поможет, но это получается то же самое, что подкидывать вслепую тяжелый топор над своей головой :)

Comment: @approximatenumber хорошо, а каким модулем в python тогда может изменять системное время в linux?

Comment: @approximatenumber ну или вообще, системные настройки в linux

Comment: @Insider можно и с помощью `os` это сделать, просто хорошо бы как-то обрабатывать то, что получается из `request.form[...]` прежде, чем передавать данные модулю `os`.

Comment: @approximatenumber просто мне бы также хотелось допустим иметь доступ для смены IP адреса, а также смены динамического или статического. С os. довольно неудобно.

Comment: @Insider с ходу не скажу, не пробовал, но с помощью гуглинга находятся всякие полезные модули, например [pynetlinux](https://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> почему "%d %s %d %d:%d:%d" не работает?

Потому что у вас `%` за скобками вызова находятся: `os.system(..) % ..`.
Нужно писать `f("%sformat%s" % ("a", 1))` вместо `f("%sformat%s") % ("a", 1)`. Даже, если это исправить, то не хорошо, не проверяя, в оболочку произвольные строки передавать.

Разбейте вашу задачу на две:

1. Распознать дату как `datetime` объект:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime

   dt = datetime.strptime(request.form['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
   ```
2. Вызвать необходимую комманду, используя полученный `datetime` объект:

   ```
   import subprocess

   subprocess.check_call(['date', '-s', str(dt)])
   ```

Это позволяет убедиться что формат даты был указан верно до попытки запуска команды и нет опасности исполнения произвольной команды (такой как удаление всех файлов).

`date -s` может требовать специальных привилегий (`root`). Эта команда не изменяет вывод `sudo hwclock --show` (hardware clock). Обычно `ntp` используется, если хочется синхронизировать время с внешним источником.

Comment: на счет безопастности, добавил аутификацию, так что, никто не может отправить или запросить что-то через GET/POST, пока, не пройдет аутификацию.

Comment: @Insider: 1- даже если вы знаете кто выполняет запрос (то есть запрос authenticated), всё равно не следует произвольные строки из интернета разрешать выполнять (принцип [Defense in Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing))). 2- даже если забыть о безопасности, удобней некорректный ввод (ошибки в формате даты) в Питоне обработать (сообщения об ошибках более полезны), до запуска системной команды.

Comment: хорошо, приму к сведению и встрою по мере возможности